# Perl read file to create array or arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, while-loop

I have some files with the following format:

```
>Age
PT 134
PT 145
PT 203
PT 237
>Karnofsky
PT 167
>Overall_Survival
PT 49
PT 126
PT 32
```

What I want to do is read a pair of files, create an array of arrays from both files then compare each combination in order looking for shared values so the final output would look like this:

```
>Age_vs_>CategoryA
PT 145
PT 203
>Karnofsky_vs_>CategoryA
NO SHARED VALUES
>Overall_Survival_vs_>CategoryA
PT 126
```

I am having trouble building my array of arrays. I have written the following code:

```
my @array
while (<FILE1>) {
        my $line = $_;
        chomp $line;
        if ( $line =~ /^>/ ) {
                @array = $line;
        }
        if ( $line !~ /^>/ ) {
                push(@array, $line);
        }
}
```

Which creates a single array of what I want to be the last element in my array of arrays. How do I create a new array each time the while loop comes across a line that starts with ">" ???

Desired data structure:

```
@File1 = (@Age, @Karnofsky, @Overall_Survival...)
@Age = ("PT 134", "PT 145", "PT 203", "PT 237")
@Karnofsky = ("PT 167")
@Overall_Survial = ("PT 49", "PT 126", "PT 32")
```

Clarification: My intention is two process pairs of files looking for every shared value between every pair of arrays. The file to be analyzed alongside the one already described might look something like this:

```
>CategoryA
PT 134
PT 155
PT 209
>CategoryB
PT 47
PT 33
PT 155
```

And the desired output would not include any comparisons within a file. So there would be NO output reading

```
>CategoryA_vs_>CategoryB
PT 155
```

Comment: An obvious AoA format does not present itself. It would help if you actually provided the desired output (data structure format) of the code you are having problem with.

Comment: I could see an AoHoA. `[ { name => 'Age', data => [ 'PT 134', ... ] }, ... ]`

Comment: It would help if the desired output that you show corresponded with the sample input. There is no `CategoryA` in your input

Answer (score 1):

```
my @File1;
my %hash;

while (my $line = <FILE1>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ( $line =~ s/^>// ) {
    push @File1, $line;
  }
  else {
    push @{ $hash{$File1[-1]} }, $line;
  }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@File1;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

Answer (score 0):

AoA:

```
my @data;
my @names;
my $i = -1;
while ( my $line = <FILE1>) {
        chomp $line;
        if ( $line =~ /^>/ ) {
                $i++;
                push @names, $line;
        }
        if ( $line !~ /^>/ ) {
                push @{$data[ $i ]}, $line;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the problem isn't very precise, but I think a hash of hashes is the best choice to achieve a reasonable level of efficiency

The program expects the pasth to the input file as a parameter on the command line

I have invented some values for `CategoryA` so that the output is equivalent to your example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @categories;
my %data;

while (<>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  chomp;
  if ( /^>/ ) {
    push @categories, $_;
  }
  elsif (@categories) {
    ++$data{$categories[-1]}{$_};
  }
}

for my $i (0 .. $#categories-1) {
  for my $j ($i+1 .. $#categories) {
    my ($cat1, $cat2) = @categories[$i, $j];
    my @shared = grep $data{$cat1}{$_}, keys %{ $data{$cat2} };
    printf "%s_vs_%s\n", $cat1, $cat2;
    print @shared ? map "$_\n", @shared : "NO SHARED VALUES\n";
  }
}
```

**data**

```
>Age
PT 134
PT 145
PT 203
PT 237
>Karnofsky
PT 167
>Overall_Survival
PT 49
PT 126
PT 32
>CategoryA
PT 126
PT 158
PT 145
PT 203
```

**output**

```
>Age_vs_>Karnofsky
NO SHARED VALUES
>Age_vs_>Overall_Survival
NO SHARED VALUES
>Age_vs_>CategoryA
PT 203
PT 145
>Karnofsky_vs_>Overall_Survival
NO SHARED VALUES
>Karnofsky_vs_>CategoryA
NO SHARED VALUES
>Overall_Survival_vs_>CategoryA
PT 126
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in my original post. I was originally just trying to figure out how to create an Array-of-Arrays and did not explain the rest of the problem clearly until my update just now.